# check element id-value in selectBox (dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if my selectbox has an id or not.

this is my code:

```
<select name="startTime" id="startTime">
    <option>23:00</option>
    <option id="nextDay">00:30</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to check wether the user has the normal one (23:00). Or the one with the id="nextDay".

So it'd be a check like this:

```
if(selected has id="nextDay"){ //Than do something}
```

How to do this with javascript and/or jquery ?
this is a simplified version of what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#startTime").change(function(){ // this can also be a form submit or something
        if($("#nextDay").is(":selected"))
        {
            alert("Working!");
                    //do something
        }
    });
});
```

This should work ;)! With the previous solution, the code was executed when the page loaded, not when the selection was made.

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work.
It even cannot get into the if statement while the selected one has the specific ID

Comment: Did you include jquery? 
Does 
    if($("#nextDay") !== undefined){
        alert("hello");
    }
give the expected output?

Comment: I did include Jquery as else my other functions wouldn't do a thing lolled :P
And this code aswell didn't work. I did get the alert box, but on both, not only on the one with the id. So i got the alert boxes at the option 23:00 and at the option 00:30. I want it to be only available at 00:30 (night times)